# JQuery plugin not working on codepen, works great elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin that I just wrote, which is so far acting just I had hoped while developing. I attempted to take this code out of my scripts directory and post it on Codepen.io. I get a script error when running it there, the error is cannot read 'Action' of undefined. It gets instantiated by a click event which passes an event. Both using jQuery 2.1. Anyone know whats happening here?

Heres the codepen:

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/uJKrL

```
// $ DOC
$.fn.dataValidate = function(event, userSettings) {
    "use strict";
    event.preventDefault();
    var api = {

        // Script definition defaults defined in object below

        notNull: {
            errorText: 'This field is required',
            symbol: false,
            Action: function(dataToCheck, instance) {
                if (dataToCheck === '' || dataToCheck === null || dataToCheck === 'undefined' || dataToCheck.length === 0 ) {
                    // if true return true to caller
                    alert('null');
                    // Retrieve errorText
                    // Wrap in error template
                    this.errorForNotNull = new api.ErrorInjector(instance);
                    return false;
                } 
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        },
        isNaN: {
            errorText: 'Numbers not allowed here',
            symbol: false,
            Action: function(dataToCheck, instance) {

                  api.notNull.Action(dataToCheck, instance); /* Reuse the notNull method as a screening service before entering into the method specific filtering (assuming null fields would be inappropriate in any types of check) */
                  if (isNaN(dataToCheck)){ // Check if the not null field is also non a number
                                    return true;
                    }
                  else {
                    this.errorForIsNan = new api.ErrorInjector(instance);
                    return false;
                  }
              }
        },
        isNum: {
            errorText: 'Please enter a number',
            symbol: false,
            Action: function(dataToCheck, instance) {
                 api.notNull.Action(dataToCheck, instance);
                  if (!isNaN(dataToCheck)){ // Check if the not null field is also non a number
                                    return true;
                    }
                  else {
                    this.errorForIsNan = new api.ErrorInjector(instance);
                    return false;
                  }
            }
        },
        isEmail: {
            errorText: 'Please enter a valid email address',
            symbol: false,
            Action: function(dataToCheck, instance) {
              api.notNull.Action(dataToCheck, instance);
              var checkEmailRegEx = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;  

              if (checkEmailRegEx.test(dataToCheck)){
              }
              else {
                this.errorForIsEmail = new api.ErrorInjector(instance);
              }

            }
        },
        isPw: {
            errorText: 'Please enter a password',
            symbol: false,
            Action: function(dataToCheck, instance) {
                api.notNull.Action(dataToCheck, instance);  
                console.log(dataToCheck);
                if (dataToCheck.length > 4){
                  var isPwRegEx = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/;
                    if(isPwRegEx.test(dataToCheck)){
                      // Multiple pw checkpoints here
                      // At least one upper case English letter
                      // At least one lower case English letter
                      // At least one digit
                      // At least one special character

                      return false;
                    }
                    else {  
                      this.errorForIsPw = new api.ErrorInjector(instance);  
                      return true;
                    }
                  }
              } // End length check for isPw


        },
        isPhoneNumber: {
            errorText: 'Please enter a valid phone number',
            symbol: false,
            Action: function(dataToCheck, instance) {
                api.notNull.Action(dataToCheck, instance);
                this.errorForIsPhoneNumber = new api.ErrorInjector(instance);
            }
        },
        isUsername: {
            errorText: 'Please enter a valid username',
            symbol: false,
            Action: function(dataToCheck, instance) {
                api.notNull.Action(dataToCheck, instance);

              var checkUsernameRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_$@*!]{3,30}$/;  

              if (checkUsernameRegEx.test(dataToCheck)){
                alert('valid username');
              }
              else {
                this.errorForIsEmail = new api.ErrorInjector(instance);
              }
            }
        },
         isNamePart: {
            errorText: 'Please enter a valid name',
            symbol: false,
            Action: function(dataToCheck, instance) {
                api.notNull.Action(dataToCheck, instance);

              var checkNamePartRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;  

              if (checkNamePartRegEx.test(dataToCheck)){
                alert('valid name part');
              }
              else {
                this.errorForIsEmail = new api.ErrorInjector(instance);
              }
            }
        },
        // New method would be added here
        errorOutput: 'validated',
        targets: ['[data-validate="notNull"]', '[data-validate="isNaN"]',
            '[data-validate="isNum"]', '[data-validate="isEmail"]', '[data-validate="isPw"]', '[data-validate="isPhoneNumber"]', '[data-validate="isUsername"]','[data-validate="isNamePart"]'],
        // Target selectors, can be modified on initialization to that of your liking, as well as have new ones added. Add a new selector target at the end of the array above
        placeholder: {
            // Template shared by each validation output error
            template: {
                defaultPlaceholderContainerStyle: 'position: relative;background:#ccc;',
                defaultPlaceholderStyle: 'position: absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;line-height:26px;height:100%;',
                // The above styles may be easily detached by simply tranfering the above CSS to a style rule matching the errorOutput class outlined above in this same object, or set on instantiation
            },
        },
        ErrorInjector: function(instance) {
            var errorNs = instance.data('validate');
            var error = '<div data-validate="output" class="' + api.errorOutput + '">' + api[errorNs].errorText + '<\/div>';
            instance.wrap('<div data-validate="output_container" class="' + api.errorOutput + '_container"><\/div>');
            instance.before(error);
        },
        acceptedTypes : ['input[type="text"]','input[type="email"]','input[type="password"]','input[type="checkbox"]','input[type="radio"]','input[type="tel"]'],
        results: {} // NS for all validation results and debugging info (see below)
    };
    // Merge the caller sent options object with the defaults. Any options set in on init from the caller will overwrite the default/internal settings

    this._overrideApiWithUserSettings = (function() {
        $.extend(true, api, userSettings);
    })();

    var targetsAll = api.targets;

    // Private utility for removing the validationOutput errors from the DOM
    this._removeThisErrorFocusThisInput = function() {
       var activeOutputPlaceholder = $(this);
       activeOutputPlaceholder.unwrap();
       activeOutputPlaceholder.remove();
       $.each(api.acceptedTypes, function(){
        var eachTypeInAcceptedTypes = this;
          activeOutputPlaceholder.find(eachTypeInAcceptedTypes).focus();
       });

       $('body').unbind('click', '.' + api.errorOutput);
    };

    $('body').on('click', '.' + api.errorOutput, this._removeThisErrorFocusThisInput);

    // Fire each module off conditionally, based on the presence of the targets set on init

    this._instantiateByDataValues = (function() { // The core of the script, carefully loadings only each modular bit of functionality by its request in the DOM via data-validate=""

        $.each(targetsAll, function( /*iteration*/ ) { /* Iterate through all of the selectors in the targets array, doing the following with each instance of them found in the DOM, passing iteration for debugging purposed only */
            var selectorTargetFromArray = $(this);
            $.each(selectorTargetFromArray, function() {
                var instance = $(this),
                    thisFnFromDomDataAttrNS = instance.data('validate');
                if (instance.length) { // If any of the selectors in the targets array are found to be in the the DOM on init

                    // Fire the constructor on the element with the data-validate="thisMethod", while passing its value to its action (all method modules and method specific functionality is named based on the selector that is responsible for its instantiation)

                    this.executeActionByCallerName = new api[thisFnFromDomDataAttrNS].Action(instance.val(), instance);
                    //! This fires off the action of the module itself off by the name of the value in the data-validate="functionNameHere"    
                } 
                else {
                    this._createNoRunLog = api.results[this] = false; // Store refs to any built in methods not used for your debugging pleasure, under the name it is called by and on
                    console.log(api.results);
                }
            });
        });
    })();
    return this;
}; // End preValidation module
```

Comment: My first guess would be some kind of race condition with the steps in the jQuery UI widget process. Double-check where you are attaching the 'validate' data to the object, and make sure it is attached by the time you are running the `_instanciateByDataValues` method.

Comment: Oh, and when I run your CodePen, it is using jQuery 1.11.0 with jQuery UI 1.10.4. May be a compatibility difference since you say you are running jQuery 2.1.

Comment: I tried it with an external load (no jQuery built in method), that was what I thought too! I am actually only using jQuery (no ui), not using their widget factory method either on this project

Comment: My bad, I didn't even pay attention to that. Oddly enough, I can get your CodePen to work fine in Firefox 32 half of the time, fails all of the time in Chrome. Dunno if that helps you troubleshoot at all, I'm out of time for the day unfortunately.

Comment: Turns out, I downloaded the complete source by going to the share => export as .zip, and what do you know aside from a css issue, the javascript is functioning just as wanted without any modifications. I guess it may not be my code causing this?

Comment: I think it has to do with the caching of the jQuery library when viewing on CodePen. They default to the v1.11 branch according to their website, and even when I used the external resources to point to a CDN for v2.0 and forced a Run, Firebug and Chrome Inspector would report v1.11 still.

Comment: I inspected it and the script it includes in the iframe checks out, it is actual, I have an alert which shows the jQuery version being used, it is using 2.1.1. Someone must know the answer to this one!

Comment: Interesting thought: try it on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on JSFiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/exsfabxr/ I guess I can rule out my code as the issue here? Seems that this is an internal Codepen.io issue?

```
$(function(){ alert('same code as above, i just wrote this because of stackoverflows "smart" validation'); window.location.href = 'http://jsfiddle.net/exsfabxr/'; });
```